# How to create bundle expansion for android on Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, bundle, assets, expansion

I have created an app that uses video a lot. I have quickly gone over the 100mb limit. I have paired the main app down to 80mb, including a selection of starter videos so that the app can be standalone on first use. I would like to use another android app bundle to deliver more content over time which I know is possible. I am using cordova to build my app (100% complete except for the additional content.) I cannot find any information or tutorial on how to actually implement this. Basically I have a folder hierarchy:

Media/Video/Full

Media/Video/SA

I would like to add content to these folders. I'm not sure what code exactly I need to write to make this a reality. Can someone help walk me through it or point me in the direction of a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Linking to the files in the bundle requires linking to the media in a different place, I was under the impression that it would dump the files into my hierarchy however it doesn't. My asset bundle was named "android_asset" So my file linking ended up looking like this:

```
    file:///android_asset/media/singalong/fivelittlemonkeysk.mp4
```